# Generating permutations with a sum constraint

Tags: r, permutation, combinatorics

I have `n` sets of variable length and would like to get all permutations of items from each set where the sum is within a certain range. For example in `R` we can do:

```
set1 <- c(10, 15, 20)
set2 <- c(8, 9)
set3 <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)

permutations <- expand.grid(set1, set2, set3)
permutations$sum <- rowSums(permutations)
final <- permutations[permutations$sum >= 25 & permutations$sum <= 29, ]

# final:
#    Var1 Var2 Var3 sum
# 3    20    8    1  29
# 5    15    9    1  25
# 8    15    8    2  25
# 11   15    9    2  26
# 14   15    8    3  26
# 17   15    9    3  27
# 20   15    8    4  27
# 23   15    9    4  28
```

This is fine for a small number of sets, however quickly (factorially) grows with larger or a greater number of sets.

**Is it possible to generate permutations that fit the constraint, without having to calculate all possibilities?**

In this example, there are no final combinations containing the 10 from `set1`, as the resulting sum would be too small no matter which other numbers are chosen. This could be useful for reducing the scope of the problem. For example, if I know that `min(set1) + max(set2) + max(set3) < 25 == TRUE`, then I can make sure to not include `min(set1)` in any permutations.

How can I generalize this, and use the constraints to prevent generating invalid permutations?

Comment: Python has the concept of a lazy-build, meaning it builds during iteration. This is preferred for memory management. R does not have an automatic means to do this, whether filtered or not. The closest I can think of is something I wrote for a previous question: [`lazyExpandGrid.R`](https://gist.github.com/r2evans/e5531cbab8cf421d14ed). It doesn't answer the "filtered" part of this question, but you can filter as-you-go and not worry so much about memory mis-use.

Comment: Clarification: *base* R doesn't have a lazy build; the [`iterators`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/iterators/index.html) package might be better, I don't know for certain.

Comment: is this knapsack sampling?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you're asking for is pretty shoe-horn specific and unlikely to be "easy to implement" (efficiently). A different way to look at it is to do the conditioning as you run the experiment (assuming this is a design for trials).

I wrote a [`lazyExpandGrid.R`](https://gist.github.com/r2evans/e5531cbab8cf421d14ed) that is similar in concept to a lazy `expand.grid`, meaning it does not evaluate all possible combinations up front. The code can be inserted later in this answer if needed, but the github-gist is fairly solid (and not short).

Using it, you should be able to do:

```
set1 <- c(10, 15, 20)
set2 <- c(8, 9)
set3 <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)

iter <- lazyExpandGrid(set1, set2, set3)

while (is.data.frame(item <- iter$nextItem())) {
  p <- sum(item)
  if (p < 25 || 29 < p) next
  print(item) # but really, do something more interesting here
}
#   Var1 Var2 Var3
# 3   20    8    1
#   Var1 Var2 Var3
# 5   15    9    1
#   Var1 Var2 Var3
# 8   15    8    2
#    Var1 Var2 Var3
# 11   15    9    2
#    Var1 Var2 Var3
# 14   15    8    3
#    Var1 Var2 Var3
# 17   15    9    3
#    Var1 Var2 Var3
# 20   15    8    4
#    Var1 Var2 Var3
# 23   15    9    4
```

Caveat emptor: the function is mostly usable, but there are certainly ways it can be improved. For instance, the use of `is.data.frame(item <- iter$nextItem())` is effectively an `isTruthy` test (name from `shiny`); currently it returns a 1-row `data.frame` until nothing remains, then returns `FALSE`. As I look at it now, that can most certainly be improved, I just haven't had the need. Feel free to comment on the github gist page if you have thoughts, bugs, etc.

Comment: This is great, thanks! I think I can make use of passing `nextItem()` the next row to visit to skip over permutations I don't want without even calculating them -- just as I was hoping could be done.