# Expand grid (or power set) with constraints

Tags: r, matrix, data.table, bigdata, powerset

This question might be too general, but I feel it comes up again and again in my work and thus is probably of interest to others.

Suppose I want to create a data table (or matrix) that is based off of expanding a grid.

```
 library(data.table)
 Vmat1 = data.table(expand.grid(c(list(d = 1:5, w = 1:(3)))))
```

Suppose however, that if I were to do this, this would result in a memory error for the true power set. However, there are constraints that I want to impose, for example:

If w>1, then it must be that d<3

This then gives smaller final set that would *not* result in a memory error:

```
Vmat1[w>1 & d<3 | w==1]
   d w
1: 1 1
2: 2 1
3: 3 1
4: 4 1
5: 5 1
6: 1 2
7: 2 2
8: 1 3
9: 2 3
```

My question is, is it possible to ex ante impose the restriction when creating the grid?  It is too costly to build the full power set and then condition and reduce.

Comment: Split into sets for expand.grid?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/50400696/3358272. (It really is the same thing ... lazily expanding a grid, like python2's `xrange`), with constraints.)

Answer (score 2):

If your concern is memory you can split into sets as @chinsoon suggests.

```
# Filter Method
V = CJ(d = 1:5, w = 1:3) # same as data.table(expand.grid(c(list(d = 1:5, w = 1:(3))))) except ordering
a <- V[w>1 & d<3 | w==1]

# Sets Method
d <- 1:5
w <- 1:3
b <- rbindlist(list(
      CJ(d = d[d < 3], w = w[w > 1]) 
    , CJ(d = d, w = w[w == 1])))

all(a == b[order(d, w)])

# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: What if you have a condition that relates the columns to one another? For example, suppose, in addition, that at the end it must always be true that, d+w<4?

Comment: Can CJ be used with lists as well? Suppose I have a list that has the possible vectors of d and w as separate elements.  This is useful is I have many variables or want to not hardcode it

Comment: You can pass the elements of a list as arguments to `CJ` (or other functions) with  `do.call(CJ, listname)`. For more complex constraints you'd need to use r2evans' function (or something like it)